# Binary Classification on a tupled dataset

Tags: algorithm, dataset, machine-learning, classification

I have a 2-class dataset on which I should apply a binary classification algorithm. The dataset looks like as follows:

a1, a2, a3, ...... +1
......
b1, b2, b3, .......-1
.......

where each feature/attribute value is a 2-tuple. For example, a1 is (a1_1, a1_2). There is dependency between a1_1 and a1_2 (though at this point I am not sure how are related) and their order is not important. Similar case holds for negative class instances too.

I am looking for some way of classifying these instances. Please let me know if such an algorithm exists.

To start with, I tried splitting the tuples - a1_1 and a1_2 formed two separate columns for an instance, leading to twice the number of feature values per instance - and used LIBSVM (C/C++) library, but the results were not good. I suppose it is not meaningful to split the tuples and hence a search for a suitable method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All things being equal, I'd imagine that if your data actually contains pairs of things, then it would be useful to communicate that fact to the learning algorithm.  **Splitting your monolithic pairs into separate features gives your classification algorithm a chance to learn about any useful relationships that might exist between the two features**.

That's just a general rule of thumb, however.  There are several reasons that you might not be getting good classification results:

1. It's possible that there is no useful relationship between the two features of a pair.  If that's the case, then splitting into two features has made your problem a lot harder: now the classification algorithm has [an additional dimension to explore](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curse_of_dimensionality).
2. Maybe you haven't found the right learning algorithm.  Different algorithms have different strengths, and it's possible that using multiple features is a fine idea provided that you use the proper classification algorithm.  I'd suggest trying a supervised learning package like [Weka](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/), which provides a really easy way to compare a bunch of learning algorithms on a single problem.  Just convert your data into `.arff` format and you'll be classifying using SVNs, decision trees, neural networks, etc. in no time.
3. You might not be providing enough features.  When you split `a1, a2, ...` into separate features `[a1_1, a1_2], [a2_1, a2_2], ...`, you could also include the reversed data as well, e.g. `[a1_1, a1_2], [a1_2, a1_1], [a2_1, a2_2], [a2_2, a2_1], ...`  For that matter, you could also use *three* features by including the non-split version for each datum, e.g. `[a1, a1_1, a1_2], [a2, a2_1, a2_2], ...`  That's kind of a "let's throw every feature we can think of at the problem" approach.
4. It could be that you just have a very hard classification problem.  Do you have any evidence that there is actually some signal in your input that a classifier could use to divide data into two groups?

Comment: I can give some more parts of my problem. The second component of each tuple (for all features), indeed, belong to an entity/instance. That is, instead of conventional single instance belonging to one class, I have two instances with same feature set belong to + / - class. It is not meaningful to split the instances into two separate + / - class instances. I have to throw entities together and call them single instance for my problem. To your points: 4) is your question answered? 1) agreed, not only does it make the problem harder, the algorithm unncessarily learns relation among the features.